# Should the development of Plus-X exposed at 64iso be adjusted?

Tags: development

I've seen it recommended to expose Plus-X 125 at 64 instead of 125, should I adjust the development to match? I'm not seeing a development time for Ilfosol-3 at 64 on the Massive development chart.This is 4x5 sheets.

Comment: What kind of difference do you expect when you deviate from the exposure rating recommended by the manufacturer?

Answer (score 1):

Overexposing Plus X and underdeveloping will flatten contrast somewhat and can reduce grain. I've only done it with Tri-X (Shot at ISO 200) but it works pretty well if you're looking for reduced contrast and grain. Try taking 20% off the development time to compensate...

Comment: Stock (125) development time according to the Massive Development Chart, is 5 minutes, Ilford's recommendation is to not go below 5 minutes due to a risk of uneven development.

Comment: @Davidw You can change the dilution of the developer as well as the time. The dev chart gives a 8.5 minute development time at 1+14 dilution of Ilfosol 3 for Plus-X, so you could do a just under 7 minutes development to pull the roll a stop. Also, even if Ilford recommends against short dev times, curiously their given development time for FP4 in Ilfosol 3 is 4.25 minutes.